# jQuery smooth scroll to anchor with a fixed menu on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a simple page with a fixed navigation that I want to smooth scroll to and ID on the page using anchor links but having some issues that seem to only occur on mobile (< 992px)

One issue is that it only scrolls correctly when the page scroll is at the very top. If I click one menu item first and the follow up by clicking on another menu item, it will scroll to what seems to be a very random place on the page. Or if I just scroll down the page a little bit and then click on a link, it brings me to a random spot on the page.

Another issue is if I click a menu item while at the top of the page and it scrolls to correct position, if I click that same link again, it scrolls all the way back to the top of the page instead of just remaining on the correct ID

This only happens when using the smooth-scrolling jQuery script. Deleting the script will cause correct anchor-linking behavior, but unfortunately no lovely, smooth scrolling

Here is my current code for the smooth scroll:

```
$('a.smooth-scroll').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 75  // height of sticky menu
    }, 1500);
});
```

Example of my Menu item:

```
<!-- MOBILE HEADER -->
<div class="wsmobileheader clearfix">
    <a href="#get-started" class="btn btn-blue font-weight-bold float-right smooth-scroll">Get Started</a>
</div>
```

Example of ID I'm trying to scroll to:

```
<section id="get-started" class="wide-40">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section-title title-centered">
            <h3 class="h3-sm">Easy To Get Started</h3>
            <p class="p-md">Start today by choosing a template and selecting a monthly plan. Your new website will be ready to go in minutues!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

**EDIT***

So I found a bit of code that seems to be responsible for my issue but I'm not really understanding the issue:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {

  /* ================== Mobile Base CSS ================== */
  html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
}
```

If I remove that media query, then everything works as expected, any ideas what in particular is causing the issue or what I could change? I may just remove it as it doesn't seem to break anything, but just trying to understand the issue.

Comment: What if you add `stop()` to prevent animation queue build up `$('html, body').stop().animate({ ... })`?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, tried adding that but getting the same result

Comment: Another suggestion is to move `event.preventDefault();` to the very top of the function

Comment: Thanks, just tried that -- updated my code in the question to reflect what I currently have. Still getting the same behavior on screens under < 992px.

Comment: Think I found the issue, I've updated my question -- any idea why that bit of CSS would cause this behavior?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce, so it's hard to tell. But in general my experience is messing around with default functionality, like the overflow of the HTML element, and putting your trust in vendor specific properties are at some point doomed to cause unexpected behavior. But glad you were able to identify the problem!